# Exporting HTML table as CSV doesn't get me the full table

Tags: javascript, jquery, csv, html-table, encodeuricomponent

So I'm using the following script to export a table do CSV where 'rows' is an Object with each row as an Object, it works just fine, but the problem is that when I download the table it just gives me the 11 first rows.
When I log the 'rows' object it shows me the full table, and 'csvContent' also shows me the full table, but when I download it it chops the table up.
In the actual script each row has more string for each column.
Any way to fix that?

```
let rows = [["row 1"], ["row 2"], ["row 3"], ["row 4"], ["row 5"], ["row 6"], ["row 7"], ["row 8"], ["row 9"], ["row 10"], ["row 11"], ["row 12"]]
let csvContent = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8," + rows.map(e => e.join(",")).join("\n");
var encodedUri = encodeURI(csvContent);
var link = document.createElement("a");
console.log(encodedUri, csvContent)
link.setAttribute("href", encodedUri);
link.setAttribute("download", "relatorio_dashapp.csv");
document.body.appendChild(link);

$('#baixar-tabela').click(e=>{link.click();})
```

Comment: *"any way to fix that"* ... not without seeing how `rows` are defined or seeing a [mcve] that reproduces the problem. Is there any pagination involved with this table?

Comment: @charlietfl added what 'rows' looks like, gonna try to reproduce the error and update. No pagination involved.